# What does this handsymbol mean?

Tags: symbols

I saw this on the news yesterday. It was a video snipped from USA where democrats and republicans were arguing. One of the republicans did the following hand symbol

[image]

Does it have a special meaning? I think it looks like the letter **W** but I don't quite understand why he should make that letter.

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/order-a-beer-like-a-german-2014-3?IR=T

Comment: @MorganFR so he is saying "3" in the american / english way? Must be a interesting discussion then..

Comment: He's either counting 3 or four depending on if his pinky is raised

Comment: Can you link to the video itself, so we can watch him make the gesture?

Comment: If it's "4" then the context may be that "Trump is president for the next 4 years".  But that's just speculation.

Comment: @JohnFeltz your right. He is using his pinky - he probably means 4 years! thx

Comment: @EsotericScreenName its from https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/heute-journal/hjo-gesamt-110.html at 12:09

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an interpretation of a hand gesture, and is not about the English language.

Comment: @choster body language is a part of the English language. I was asking what this hand symbol means and MorganFR comment was sufficent to explain this. I agree with you that body language is not the major topic of this page, but I think its within this scope of English language so I do not see a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the hand sign for the number four:

[image]

It's not clear from the video what the relevance is, though. A popular chant in support of a President is "four more years", though that doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of Donald Trump's recent election.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common hand symbol in the U.S.  It may have special meaning to a particular group of people, like a [gang sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_signal) (only in this case the "gang" is a group of Republican voters).

[White supremacist groups have been known to use various signs](http://www.adl.org/combating-hate/hate-on-display/summary-view.html?hate_symbol_category=racist-hand-signs) to identify each other and express their views.  However, this is not one of those on this list.

It's possible it isn't a hand sign at all, just a meaningless gesture.  If it is an actual hand sign, then I expect it's unknown to the average American.

Comment: It could be a disguised way of 'giving the finger' (the middle finger). A colleague and I sometimes lightheartedly gestured with three fingers together.

Comment: @Sydney "read between the lines"?  :)